# StringBuilder as class member?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Is it efficient (or necessary?) to make `StringBuilder` a member of class, and use it in class methods whenever string concatenation is to be done?

Or just use new `StringBuidler()` before such operations?

I suspect it is efficient if there is a `StringBuilder` ready for use there.

Xing

Comment: The fresh `StringBuilder` is not expensive to initialize. Don't optimize the wrong things

Comment: Depends on the use case. But `StringBuilder` shouldn't be too expensive to allocate. And if that's a problem, you can always create a pool of builders to use. Generally creating a class level member will hurt if you want thread-safety.

Comment: It really depends.. If you have many many methods (like hundreds, which makes not too much sense for me) then having a member makes sense... but as long as this happens only a few time the overhead is really negligible.

Comment: Creating and releasing a StringBuilder when you need it will be more efficient from a memory perspective - if you have it as a class member it will not go out of scope until the object does, and some objects can live for a long time.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Performance should not matter but other reasons like thread safety(with local variables instead of class members) or the option to access the `StringBuilder` from other methods if that's necessary which isn't possible if it's a local variable. In general i try to limit the scope/accessibility of a variable as much as possible.

Comment: Benchmark tests on this exact question: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-cache (but there's a typo in the final result section, the cached one is actually faster)

Answer (score 4):

It's an interesting question, and one that's been [researched](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-cache).

The answer is, **yes**, *under extreme test conditions* it's more efficient to share a single instance and reuse it than it is to create a new `StringBuilder` each time.

But, **no**, it's almost never necessary, and probably a bad idea in most cases. Other considerations like thread-safety are generally more important than micro-optimizing prematurely.

The following code from the [linked article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-cache) does a highly artificial performance test:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static string Method1()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string value in _array)
            builder.Append(value);
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    static StringBuilder _builder = new StringBuilder();

    static string Method2()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = _builder;
        builder.Clear();
        foreach (string value in _array)
            builder.Append(value);
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    static string[] _array = { "dot", "net", "perls", "string", "array" };
    const int _max = 1000000;
    static void Main()
    {
        Method1();
        Method2();

        // Version 1: use new StringBuilder each time.
        var s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < _max; i++)
        {
            Method1();
        }
        s1.Stop();

        // Version 2: reuse a single StringBuilder instance.
        var s2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < _max; i++)
        {
            Method2();
        }
        s2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(s2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The result (I've just run it myself):

- Repeated allocation:    146.21
- StringBuilder as field: 98.96

Comment: It's one of these micro optimization questions which are irrelevant in practice. Most times other arguments should matter like readability, maintainability, (thread-)safety, accessibility, encapsulation, reusability. Also, there are often other things that can be improved. I don't see a reason to call a method that uses a large loop millions of times. I could use a single loop with a greater loop-counter instead(for example).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I agree entirely - but as an academic question it's still interesting. I've stated in my answer that in almost any realistic situation it's not going to be relevant.

Comment: yes, but what will stick in your memory is that it's indeed better for performance reasons to use a single `StringBuilder` which isn't true in reality. So people will use a class member `StringBuilder` with no performance gain but with possible threading issues in future or simply wrong results if one method manipulates the content while the other method doesn't expect it. It's introducing unneeded complexity and dependencies. The `StringBuilder` is a tool to create a String. This might be stored as a field in the class since it is a property of that type, not the `StringBuilder` itself.

Comment: RAM's are not more expensive than your time, come on, I would prefer maintainability, readability instead of 146 - 98 = 48 less allocation.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Understand your point, but I'm not sure I quite see it that way. I try to answer people's questions accurately and with all the information to make their own decisions as programmers. Is it more efficient? *Yes* ... How can you tell that? *here's the code* ... Does that mean it's a good idea? *No, and this is why*. ..  Now you decide what to do...